# Why $\rm ZnO$ looks transparent?

Tags: visible-light, physical-chemistry, nanoscience

I'm looking for the reason transparent of $\rm ZnO$ and found out nanoparticles of $\rm ZnO$ do not scatter reflected light
can I conclude like this: material can be transparent if pass light or reflected light without change
sorry if my question is a little bit ridiculous:(

Comment: Can you emphasize (or expand upon) what "material can be transparent if pass light or reflected light without change" means? Because if it reflects light then it isn't transparent but additionally it can also absorb light which will make it not transparent, which isn't included in your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Feynman in [Chapter 31 The Origin of the Refractive Index](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html) explains that the response to electromagnetic waves is a function of frequency of the waves and there is more information in [Chapter 32 Refractive Index of Dense Materials](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_32.html).
In simple terms this dependence is as a result of the electrons in a material having natural frequencies and the incoming em wave forcing those electrons to oscillate.
If the natural frequency of the electrons is not close to the frequency of the em waves then the em waves can travel through the material with very little absorption, the material is transparent.
However, if the frequency of the incoming electromagnetic wave is close to a natural frequency the em wave is absorbed by the material, the material is opaque.

You state that ZnO is transparent and I assume that means in the visible part of the em spectrum.  The reason is that there are no resonances available for absorption of em waves in that part of the spectrum but if one moves into the UV part of the spectrum ZnO does absorb em waves and that is why it is used as a sun block.
The reason for the absorption is the fact that for ZnO there is a band gap between the valence and conduction bands of approximately $3.3\,\rm eV$ which corresponds the energy of photons of wavelength $370\,\rm nm$.  Thus photons of this and shorter wavelengths can promote electrons from the valence band to the conduction band, hence the UV photons are absorbed, just what is what is required of a sunblock.

Small ($\approx \mu\rm m$) particles of ZnO scatter light and that is what gives ZnO its white appearance.
However, if the ZnO is in the form of nano particles ($1 - 100\,\rm nm$) then light in the visible part of the spectrum is not scattered by the nano particles and so ZnO appears transparent which in terms of being used as a sun block is good news as the sun block no longer appears white when applied to the skin.